# EKS autoscaler HA configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling, amazon-eks

I have the following configuration:

- installed EKS using terraform module
  https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v4.0.2/examples/basic/main.tf
- added multi-asg autoscaler
  (https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md)
- configured working group to run 1 instance per az (in az-1a and az-1b
  and pod per instance)

When I change POD spec/config I see the next:

- new instance creation (2 running)

  - 2 pods in state running and 1 in pending
- new instance created (3 running)

  - 2 pods in state running (age updated for both)
  - 2 pods running on instances in one az
  - 2 running instances in 1 az after scale-down timeout

Is there a proper way to configure autoscaler to create instances/pods in different 2 azs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two levels to this. The cluster autoscaler instance location and then the kubernetes pod location.

Create an auto scaling group for each availability zone:

> - Cluster autoscaler does not support Auto Scaling Groups which span
>     multiple Availability Zones; instead you should use an Auto Scaling
>     Group for each Availability Zone and enable the
>     [`--balance-similar-node-groups`](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#im-running-cluster-with-nodes-in-multiple-zones-for-ha-purposes-is-that-supported-by-cluster-autoscaler) feature. If you do use a single Auto Scaling Group that spans multiple Availability Zones you will find
>     that AWS unexpectedly terminates nodes without them being drained
>     because of the [rebalancing feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/auto-scaling-benefits.html#arch-AutoScalingMultiAZ).

Then for kubernetes, use pod [anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) on the [EKS populated `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone` label](https://eksworkshop.com/assigning_pods/affinity/).

EBS Volumes don't span availability zones so if you are using persistent volumes you may get stuck with pods in one zone or worst case pods that won't schedule.

Comment: thanks, missed this info. it works ok with instances, but at the one time - old pod and one new pod are running. i didn't managed to configure it in blue\green fashion and not sure if it possible.